# Global Mouse and KeyBoard Hooks

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Estoy capturando los eventos globales del Mouse y Teclado y guardando las coordenadas `x`, `y` donde hace los eventos; para ello estoy utilizando *hooks* (lo obtuve de [Processing Global Mouse and Keyboard Hooks in C#](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7294/Processing-Global-Mouse-and-Keyboard-Hooks-in-C)).

Quiero capturar ciertas combinaciones de Teclas, por ejemplo:

```
Ctrl+a,
Ctrl+c,
Ctrl+v,
Tab,
Enter
```

El programa **demasiado** bien: guarda los eventos de **todas** las teclas presionadas. Es decir, si presiono Ctrl+c, graba las siguientes cinco lineas:

```
KeyDown,   LControlKey,    x,  y
KeyDown,   C,              x,  y
KeyPress,  [],             x,  y
KeyUp,     LControlKey,    x,  y
KeyUp,     C,              x,  y
```

Lo que quisiera es guardar la combinación de teclas en una sola linea, es decir:

```
KeyPress, LControlKey+C, x, y
```

En la pagina del programa comentan que es posible capturar las combinaciones de tecla solo que hay que agregar tres eventos para capturarlos, pero realmente no se a que se refieran con ello.

El código es el siguiente, Instancia global del objeto hooks:

```
 private void loadData()
    {
        actHook = new UserActivityHook();
        actHook.OnMouseActivity += new MouseEventHandler(MouseMoved);
        actHook.KeyDown += new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyDown);
        actHook.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(MyKeyPress);
        actHook.KeyUp += new KeyEventHandler(MyKeyUp);

        actHook.Stop();
        
    }
```

Este es el método que graba los movimientos en el listView:

```
private void LogWrite(string txt)
    {
        string[] lineItems = txt.Split('-');
        lv = new ListViewItem(txt);
        lv.Text = lineItems[0]; // en un array y obtienes la posición 1
        lv.SubItems.Add(lineItems[1]);//Posicion 2
        lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_x.Text.ToString());//Posision 3
        lv.SubItems.Add(lbl_y.Text.ToString());// Posicion 4
        listCaptura.Items.Add(lv);
        count = count + 1;

    }
```

Y con estos eventos en el teclado invoca al metodo LogWrite:

```
public void MyKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        LogWrite("KeyDown - " + e.KeyData.ToString());
    }

    public void MyKeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        LogWrite("KeyPress - " + e.KeyChar);
    }

    public void MyKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        LogWrite("KeyUp - " + e.KeyData.ToString());
    }
```

Así es como los graba y lo que espero obtener:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿ Que es lo que tendría que agregar en el código para realizar las capturas de las combinaciones de teclas ?

Erick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estuve revisando y lo que menciona es que puedes establecer banderas pero eso funcionaría para una combinación en específico. Para cualquier combinación, podrías intentar llevar un registro de las teclas que se han presionado y cuáles se han soltado para ver las combinaciones que se han formado:

```
      // Keys que se han presionado
      private List<string> KeysPressed = new List<string>();

      // Keys que se han presionado y no se han soltado
      private List<string> CurrentKeysPressed = new List<string>();

      public void MyKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
      {
         KeysPressed.Add(e.KeyData.ToString());
      }

      public void MyKeyUp(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
      {
         var key = e.KeyData.ToString();

         var keyPressed = CurrentKeysPressed.SingleOrDefault(i=>i == key);
         if(keyPressed != null)
            CurrentKeysPressed.Remove(keyPressed);

         // Aquí deberás decidir cuándo finalizar una combinación
         // Por ejemplo:
         //  a) La combinación se finaliza cuando se suelta una tecla:
         //       Presionas ctrl + c, sueltas c y aprietas a y sueltas ctrl + a
         //         => Se tendrán las filas en el List View: 
         //                  Down ctrl + c
         //                  Up ctrl + c
         //                  Down a
         //                  Up a
         //  b) Se finaliza cuando ninguna tecla está presionada:
         //       Presionas ctrl + c, sueltas c y aprietas a y sueltas ctrl + a
         //         => Se tendrán las filas:
         //                  Down ctrl + a
         //                  Up ctrl + a

         // Caso b. si es el caso a o algún otro, es cuestión de que implementes la lógica.
         bool terminarCombinacion = CurrentKeysPressed.Count < 1;
         if(terminarCombinacion){
            if(KeysPressed.Count>1){
               var combination = string.Join("+", KeysPressed.ToArray());
               LogWrite("Down -" + combination);
               LogWrite("Up -" + combination);
            }
            else
            {
               LogWrite("Key Down -" + key);
               LogWrite("Key Up -" + key);
            }

            KeysPressed.Clear();
         }
      }
```

Comment: Excelente muchas gracias, me ha servido de momento caso "b" es lo que necesito, pero igual no descarto un caso "a".
Analizare bien la lógica y códigos.
Saludos
Erick.